# Error when install RosettaCommon using Scons

Tags: macos, clang, scons, rosetta

I'm building release executables for RosettaCommons, I input to the terminal with the following code:

```
scons bin mode=release
```

And I got the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Running versioning script ... Release package detected, using rosetta/main/.release.json to acquire version information...
Done. (0.0 seconds)
Number of option files updated: 0
Total 4580 options.
Finished updating ResidueProperty code
-- no changes needed
Finished updating VariantType code
-- no changes needed
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
clang++ -o build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default/libzlib.dylib -dynamiclib -install_name /Users/miotomato/Downloads/rosetta_bin_mac_2021.16.61629_bundle/main/source/build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default/libzlib.dylib -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-rpath=/Users/miotomato/Downloads/rosetta_bin_mac_2021.16.61629_bundle/main/source/build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/../lib build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default/dummy_zlib.os -Lexternal/lib -Lbuild/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default -Lexternal -L/usr/lib
ld: unknown option: -rpath=/Users/miotomato/Downloads/rosetta_bin_mac_2021.16.61629_bundle/main/source/build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [build/external/release/macos/10.16/64/x86/clang/12.0/default/libzlib.dylib] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I list the version of each program:

```
macOS Monterey 12.0 Beta
Scons 4.2.0
Python 2.7.16
RosettaCommons 2021.16.61629
```

Comment: Which os? which version of SCons? which version of python? URL to the project you're trying to build? Have you tried contacting the RosettaCommons project?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have updated my question. I'm installing RosettaCommons and use Scons in the rosetta/main/source folder as they suggested on their website. I try to post the same question on RosettaCommons forum but my account is still pending approval.

Comment: SCons 4.2.0 is python 3.5+ only. So you must be using a version newer than 2.7.16

Comment: I update python to 3.8 and still get the same error.

Comment: You're issue is not related to SCons itself. Most likely it's the build system RosettaProject build using SCons.  Please paste the output of `scons --version`.  Most likely the -rpath shouldn't be specified for compiling on mac.. Could have something to do with monterey's version changing from 11.x to 12.0.   But most likley the answer will come from someone familiar with RoseetaCommons project's build.   You might search for -rpath in their SConstruct/SConscripts.. and see if the logic makes sense for macos